# #Ref! error in excel formula

Tags: reference, excel-formula, ref

I have used my formula

```
=SUM(D8:D11)-D12-D13-D14-D15
```

My main data in `D1` to `D11`. Sometimes `D12`, `D13`, `D14` & `D15` data will be blank. Then I will remove the above `D12`, `D13`, `D14`, `D15` data. Then It will be #ref! error.

Are there any solutions to avoid #ref! error.

[image: #ref! error sample is here]

Comment: With your screen capture, we cannot tell row or column references.  Is is safe to assume that D1 is 385,373.00?

Answer (score 0):

Well part of the problem you will face will is the variability of the number of rows you have.  I was looking at your number columns and I made the assumption that anything with a number less than 5 in column C you are adding, and anything greater than 4 in Column C you are subtracting.  In the row where you have the total and you are having your error use the following.

```
=SUMIF(Reference Range, Criteria, Range to Sum from)
```

Which for you translates to:

```
=SUMIF($C1:$C9,"<"&5,D1:D9)-SUMIF($C1:$C9,">=5",D1:D9)
```

Because I did not lock the D column I can copy this one column to the right and the D references will change to E.

The main thing this is doing is taking the sum of everything that has a value in column C less than 5 and then subtracting the sum of everything that has a value of greater than or equal to 5 in column C.

Now if the assumption about those values in column C are incorrect let us know because we could also do it for subtracting anything starting with Depreciation.

Comment: Ok Sir, Thanks a lot. This formula is actual for my. But here is a little problem in other file same as my attach file. sorry I can't attach image. When in column C3 is 1 & c5 is 2, other cell will blank. I mean that C2:C9 have only two cell number & other cell may be blank. Then it count only Criteria 1 & 2. But What formula will be correct to calculate full d column

Comment: 1) IS the assumption about column C correct.  2)  Since your screen shot cut off row and column reference letters and numbers, is the assumption that D1 has a value of 385,373.00 correct? 3) How do you distinguish which rows will be added and which rows you will subtract since not all rows will always be there.